# Elliptic Distributions vs Rotationally Invariant Distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

I'm trying to understand the difference between Elliptic and Rotationally invariant distributions.

Previously, for some reason, I was under the impression that the Gaussian distribution was the only rotationally invariant distribution, i.e. it is the only distribution with the property that
$$f(\mathbf{x}) = f(\Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert) =f(\Vert R \mathbf{x} \Vert)=f(R\mathbf{x}),$$
where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $R$ is an $n \times n$ orthogonal matrix, since $\Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert = \Vert R  \mathbf{x} \Vert$.

Looking at the wikipedia article on [Elliptic distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_distribution#Spherical_distribution), assuming $0$ mean and diagonal covariance matrix their pdfs have the form
$$f(x) = k \cdot g( \Vert \mathbf{x} \Vert ),$$ where $k$ is some scaling factor.

Doesn't this mean that elliptic distributions with $0$ mean and diagonal covariance matrix ($0$ centered spherical distributions), are rotationally invariant? Is it true that the Gaussian distribution is not the only rotationally invariant distribution?

Comment: Related: [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316617/definition-spherical-distribution)